# jQuery Disabled Checkbox Array By Value

Tags: jquery, checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" class="largecheckbox" name="chk_wms[]" value="m1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="largecheckbox" name="chk_wms[]" value="m2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="largecheckbox" name="chk_wms[]" value="m3" />
<input type="checkbox" class="largecheckbox" name="chk_wms[]" value="m4" />
```

How can I disable m1 and m3?
I tried:

```
J("input:checkbox[name=chk_wms[value='m1']]").attr("disabled", true);
```

And I would like to combine the command in one jQuery call something like:

```
J("input:checkbox[name=chk_wms[value='m1']], input:checkbox[name=chk_wms[value='m3']] ").attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: by the way if 1,3 is consistent you could use 'odd' selector that would do the trick

Comment: by the way this awfully complicated selector and overly specific on the left side that should be less specific., you don't really need the name selector etc..

Comment: I find your question hard to understand in this format - could you edit refine your question or start a new one?

Comment: @alonisser
I created another question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270028/jquery-one-call-several-actions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your attribute selector is incorrect.  You've nested the attribute selector when really you need to make them siblings.  Additionally you need to escape the `[]` in the name of the checkbox. Try the following

```
J('input:checkbox[name="chk_wms\[\]"][value="m1"]').attr('disabled', true);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xMwMQ/

Comment: by the way - if when you say disable you mean unchecked you should replace attr with .prop("checked",false)

Comment: great - than you should except this answer (by @JaredPar) -asking good questions and excepting good answers is what drives this community

Answer (score 1):

use prop instead

```
J('input:checkbox[name="chk_wms"][value="m1"]').prop('disabled', true);
```