# jQuery one call several actions

Tags: jquery, performance, checkbox

Reading several guidelines for jQuery performance I discovered this functionality:

Instead of doing:

```
$('#legendGallery).draggable({containment:'#container'});
$('#caption').draggable({containment:'#container'});
$('#controls').draggable({containment:'#container'});
```

Do this:

```
$('#legendGallery, #caption, #controls').draggable({containment:'#container'});
```

(One call to the jQuery engine several actions applied)

I want to apply this concept to an array of checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="largecheckbox" name="chk_wms[]" value="m1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="largecheckbox" name="chk_wms[]" value="m2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="largecheckbox" name="chk_wms[]" value="m3" />
<input type="checkbox" class="largecheckbox" name="chk_wms[]" value="m4" />
```

With the following code I want to disable several checkboxes:

```
$('input:checkbox[name="chl_wms\[\]"][value="m1"]', 'input:checkbox[name="chl_wms\[\]"][value="m2"]', 'input:checkbox[name="chl_wms\[\]"][value="m3"]).prop('disabled', true);
```

But it's not working, no error and no action applied.

Is there a better way to define the selectors?
Is there a way to do that command using one single call?

Thanks!

Comment: `$('input:checkbox[name="ch**L**_wms\[\]"]...` Typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be a typo in your selctors. Plus, the jQuery escape char is `\\`, and each selector should be in one string. With that in mind it should be:

```
$('input:checkbox[name="chk_wms\\[\\]"][value="m1"], input:checkbox[name="chk_wms\\[\\]"][value="m2"], input:checkbox[name="chk_wms\\[\\]"][value="m3"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

By fixing that it should work.

An alternative method which would perform better than the attribute selector would be to use classes. Eg:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="largecheckbox flag-disabled" name="chk_wms[]" value="m1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="largecheckbox flag-disabled" name="chk_wms[]" value="m2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="largecheckbox flag-disabled" name="chk_wms[]" value="m3" />
<input type="checkbox" class="largecheckbox" name="chk_wms[]" value="m4" />    
----
$(".flag-disabled").prop("disabled", "disabled");
```

Or even better yet, use Ids:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="largecheckbox" id="chk_wms[m1]" name="chk_wms[]" value="m1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="largecheckbox" id="chk_wms[m2]" name="chk_wms[]" value="m2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="largecheckbox" id="chk_wms[m3]" name="chk_wms[]" value="m3" />
<input type="checkbox" class="largecheckbox" id="chk_wms[m4]" name="chk_wms[]" value="m4" />    
----
$("#chk_wms\\[m1\\], #chk_wms\\[m2\\], #chk_wms\\[m3\\]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: $('input:checkbox[name="chk_wms\\[\\]"][value="m1"], input:checkbox[name="chk_wms\\[\\]"][value="m2"], input:checkbox[name="chk_wms\\[\\]"][value="m3"]).prop('disabled', true);

Using this I got a JS error. The same using only one \
I will try soon the second solution. The list is composed of 50 elements, it takes time.

Comment: the first method works fine - just a type there with missing ' in the end of the selector - I'll also edit @rory_mccrossan answer to reflect it - I believe you should accept it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but why can you not just do:

```
$('.largecheckbox').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: That would disable all checkboxes, OP is leaving the last checkbox, `m4`, active.

Comment: If you are good with RegEx, fine and good. Otherwise disable all the checkboxes and enable the one you want to. Does that not work?

Comment: I need to disable only several checkboxes depending on the value.
I have a general click event based on the .largecheckbox class. The list is composed of 50 checkboxes, depending on the checked one I reload a map, but several checkboxes must be disabled depending on the map callback result.